# Evaluating: $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac1t\int_0^t\sin(\alpha x)\cos(\beta x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I tried evaluating the integral but maybe there's an easier way. Please help.

Here is what I did:

$\begin{aligned}\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac1t\int_0^t \sin(\alpha x)\cos(\beta x)dx&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac1t\int_0^t\frac12(\sin(\alpha x+\beta x)+\sin(\alpha x-\beta x))dx\\&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac1{2t}\left(\frac{\cos((\alpha-\beta)t)}{\alpha-\beta}-\frac{\cos((\alpha+\beta)t)}{\alpha+\beta}-2\right)\end{aligned}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Were you able to evaluate the integral?  What happened then?

Comment: I obtained something in terms of cosines so I think the limit is zero, since the cosines are bounded, but i wasnt sure if this was correct

Comment: Please include your work in the question. It will help people give better feedback/answers

Comment: Your solution is indeed correct.

Comment: @martycohen thanks a lot

Comment: I think the person who voted to close the question before editing (both the vote and the edit after were justified at that moment) to retract the close vote because there is no need for this question to be in the close queue after all since the OP included his/her own work/attempts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed a simple way. Express each sine and cosine in terms of exponentials via Euler formula. Multiply things together. The "infinite time average" of exponentials is straightforward. Make sure you pay attention to all the cases (e.g. $\alpha=\pm \beta$).

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: The cosines work just as well with no need for complex values.

Comment: Can you provide the link to (the specific) Euler formula?

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- it's $\cos(x)=(e^{ix} +e^{-i x})/2$ and so on.

Comment: Oh that. Got it.